# How do I bind text of checkbox to Header of Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have an Expander that contains 3 checkbox.

```
<Expander Header="Bind Here" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
     <StackPanel >
          <CheckBox>Test 1</CheckBox>
          <CheckBox>Test 2</CheckBox>
          <CheckBox>Test 3</CheckBox>
     </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

I want to append the text of a checked checkbox to the Header of the expander.

Is it possible using binding?

Comment: No. you can just bind the content of many checkboxes to Expander header but you can't add the checkbox checked condition in binding. You have to write code behind logic to achieve this.

Comment: please see my answer. where using a converter we can achieve the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers but here's what I did:

```
<Expander Header="{Binding SelectedTitle}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
 <StackPanel >
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.isTest1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Test 1</CheckBox>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.isTest2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Test 2</CheckBox>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.isTest3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">Test 3</CheckBox>
 </StackPanel>
```

```
 public String SelectedTitle
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                if (SelectedItem.isTest1)
                    builder.Append("Browse subfolders, ");
                if (SelectedItem.isTest2)
                    builder.Append("Enter filename at the panel, ");
                if (SelectedItem.isTest3)
                    builder.Append("Always show scan settings, ");
                if (builder.Length == 0)
                    builder.Append("None");


            return builder.ToString().Trim().TrimEnd(',');
        }
    }

private void SelectedItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateProperty("SelectedTitle");
    }
```

Comment: There is one problem(typical WPF problem) in this kind of solution. if the SelectedItem.isTest1 value is set anytime in ViewModel/ Codebehind. you have to make sure to raise property change for "SelectedTitle". But putting this logic in a binding layer make sure that if ever, anyhow any bound value is changed your logic always work out it's way to view without the need to raise the change. your logic is good and also working here but it's a good design practice to use converts & dependency properties(needless to say much more performance efficient too.) :)

Answer (score 0):

When your checkbox is checked you need to track if it has been checked or not, you can do this either by binding or event handling or triggers.

Following is a quick example

---

### Using Binding (XAML Only)

if you are keen to have it as binding you can try having triggers and setters on control template for expander like this (I leave it to user to edit and produce a minimal xaml the following piece works but may not be minimal) --

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplate" TargetType="Expander">
        <Expander x:Name="MyExpander">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <CheckBox x:Name="Box1">Test 1</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="Box2">Test 2</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox x:Name="Box3"> Test 3</CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger  SourceName="Box1" Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Header"
                        TargetName="MyExpander"
                        Value="{Binding Content, ElementName=Box1 }" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Box2"
                     Property="CheckBox.IsChecked"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Header" TargetName="MyExpander"
                        Value="{Binding Content, ElementName=Box2 }" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="Box3"
                     Property="CheckBox.IsChecked"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Header"
                        TargetName="MyExpander"
                        Value="{Binding Content, ElementName=Box3 }" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Expander Template="{StaticResource ControlTemplate}"/>
```

---

or if you don't mind code behind

## Code Behind Way

```
private void ToggleButton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkBox = ((CheckBox) sender);

        if (checkBox.IsChecked != null && checkBox.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            MyExpander.Header = checkBox.Content.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Xaml --

```
<Expander x:Name="MyExpander">
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">Test 1</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox  Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">Test 2</CheckBox>
        <CheckBox  Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">Test 3</CheckBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

Comment: What will happen if all the check boxes are checked and after checking if it is again unchecked ( whithout checking another checkbox)

Comment: last one selected will always be set, and I guess its straight forward to change as is needed

Comment: the question was to "append the text of a checked checkbox to the Header of the expander" not just replace it with lsat checked cehckbox.

Comment: once you tell OP on how to bind I don't think its difficult to append or do whatever, idea should be to motivate learning than spoon feeding !

Comment: true that but a person who is posting the answer should differentiate the answer and/or  the approach clearly. anyone else will understand that you don't know the answer yourself clearly so just pasted some code. And if you are just trying him to undertone the binding at least try to tell it explicitly that what have you done and what part needs to be done. I don;t want to criticize your approach but you mention that it's straight forward to change as needed and you think  implementing Checked event is not.that's the irony in your answer.

Comment: dude checked event is trivial isn't ? but anyway boss, thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool way to do so:**(Binding + Converter)**

**XAML:**

```
 <Expander Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="expander" Width="500">
            <Expander.Resources>
                <local:ExpanderHeaderConverter x:Key="ExpanderHeaderConverter" />
            </Expander.Resources>
            <Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock >
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ExpanderHeaderConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName="c1" Mode="OneWay"/>        
                            <Binding ElementName="c1" Mode="OneWay" Path="IsChecked"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="c2" Mode="OneWay"/>         
                            <Binding ElementName="c2" Mode="OneWay" Path="IsChecked"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="c3" Mode="OneWay"/>
                            <Binding ElementName="c3" Mode="OneWay" Path="IsChecked"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Expander.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Name="c1" >Test 1</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Name="c2">Test 2</CheckBox>
                <CheckBox Name="c3">Test 3</CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Expander>
```

**Converter:**

```
public class ExpanderHeaderConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i+=2)
        {
            if ((values[i + 1] as bool?) == true)
                output += (values[i] as CheckBox).Content.ToString()+" ";
        }
        return output;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]